# Angular Service Worker: 404 on Sub Route Refresh

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

[image]Tried manifest routing as well to redirect to index but didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: post your code and what you tried.

Comment: what do you want exactly ? if the route dosen't exist should redirect to index ?

Comment: I have provided some route to dataGroup for caching the API data and it work as expected but once i hit refresh on that then 404 comes

Comment: Also i did notice that SW cache storage clears once i refresh..

Comment: same issue on my side.any luck?

Comment: No buddy !.....